# Настройки маршрутизации для ethernet и wi-fi адаптера

Tags: маршрутизация

Схема корпоративной сети: [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z7GLphtpAsMzfNNYbFFdPZvKCk1_1dcB). Я в подсети №5. Могу ходить в другие подсети и главную сеть через шлюз 10.2.0.1 (я так понимаю, что стоит proxy) Поскольку мои машины за NAT в роутере DIR-615 10.1.0.1 (видится как 10.2.5.199/255.255.0.0/10.2.0.1 и DNS 10.2.0.1/8.8.8.8), то ко мне могут ходить, если я только проброшу им порты на конкретные мои машины (но мне это и не надо, главное чтобы мы могли ходить в главную сеть, а не они к нам :). Мне очень нужно ходить на машину моей подсети (10.1.0.13/255.255.255.0/10.1.0.1 DNS 10.1.0.1/8.8.8.8) через radmin из сторонних интернетов, но дальше 10.2.0.1 порты закрыты и нету варианта договориться с главным админом, поэтому я сделал так: подрубил wi-fi адаптер (192.168.0.250/255.255.255.0/192.168.0.1 и DNS: 192.168.0.1/8.8.8.8) и подключился к wi-fi сети соседа, настроил на тамошнем роутере ddns и сделал проброс порта на radmin, но я могу лишь подключаться если удалю шлюз и DNS 10.1.0.1 на ethernet-адаптере. Мне нужно и ходить к себе в комп и чтобы сохранился доступ сервера главной сети 192.168.1.247, 192.168.1.249 и 192.168.11 10.1.0.1 .. Помогите как грамотно настроить маршрутизацию...

Comment: Нарисуйте схему (пока мало что понятно) с указанием узлов (по одному узлу в каждой подсети плюс все маршрутизаторы/роутеры), их интерфейсов, настроек интерфейсов, и перечислением требуемых доступов. Заодно поясните, нафига доступ в корпоративную сеть организован через NAT, а не напрямую.

Comment: И обязательно укажите операционную систему маршрутизатора (на котором вот те сеть N1 и N2 (wi-fi). В linux вам надо сделать вторую таблицу маршрутизации (с помощью `ip route add table 2 default via шлюз`) в которую положить шлюз для второй сети. И написать правило маршрутизации по которому все пакеты с исходящим ip второй сети шли бы через эту вторую таблицу (`ip rule add prio XXX from IP-второй-сети lookup 2`). Добавить по вкусу дополнительные правила, что отправлять через вторую таблицу

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за ответ. схема: [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z7GLphtpAsMzfNNYbFFdPZvKCk1_1dcB) структуру сети всю не знаю. моя подсеть 5 и все машины за NAT в роутере DIR-615 10.1.0.1 (так сделал прежний админ, он внутри подсети поставил ещё и свой proxy на почту и инет, но я его сейчас отрубил :). все подсети ходят на 10.2.0.1.. через tracert на ip гугла.. дальше 10.2.0.1 куда я иду не показывает. Все подсети общаются между собой и с главной сетью через 10.2.0.1. но я могу видеть и главную сеть и мне нужен доступ на сервера 192.168.1.247, 192.168.1.249 и 192.168.11

Comment: @Mike, спасибо. в локалке 10.1.0.1 = DIR-615 Hw ver. E4 Fw ver. 5.10RU, сторонний wi-fi 192.168.0.1 = TL-WR941ND v5.0 прошивка 3.14.19 Build 130509 Rel. 63583n. у меня на всех машинах windows 7 либо xp. мне нужно оставлять шлюз и dns на обеих сетевухах? вот только в локалке: [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w1HNIsNv_N0RInuCGs5eoS-cxYy0Smls) , а вот когда подключаю wi-fi адаптер: [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vll92fydltREz2tgs-vC6SLFLcwE95BP)

Comment: вопрос снова всплыл. тема актуальна. кто-нибудь может помочь в разрешении ситуации? сервер в моей рабочей подсети планируется подключить через wi-fi адаптер, а на роутере поставить dyndns, чтобы я мог ходить на эту машину везде, где есть инет. но нужно, чтобы я когда законнектился я мог ходить на сервера 192.168.Х.Х, пользоваться браузером.. кароч всем тем, что позволяет встроенная вторая ethernet карта. очень нужна помощь. спасибо.